# Socket IO: failed: There was a bad response from the server (only from IOS Devices)

Tags: node.js, react-native, ionic-framework, websocket, socket.io

I have this weird issue which only occurs on IOS devices. Android devices are fine.

Client:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    if (socket) {
      socket.removeAllListeners();

      if (socket.listeners("connect").length === 0) {
        socket.on('connect', () => {
          console.log('connected')
          dispatch(setSupportStatus(true));
        })
      }

      if (socket.listeners("message").length === 0) {
        socket.on('message', (data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
          if (data.chatRoomId == support.selectedChatRoom?.id) {
            dispatch(addActiveChat(data));
          } else {
            //create notification badge
            dispatch(setNewMessage({ id: data.chatRoomId, value: true }));
          }
        })
      }

      if (socket.listeners("close-chat-room").length === 0) {
        socket.on('close-chat-room', (id: string) => {
          dispatch(closeChatRoom(id));
        })
      }

      if (socket.listeners("disconnect").length === 0) {
        socket.on('disconnect', (data: any) => {
          console.log('disconnected');
          dispatch(setSupportStatus(false));
        })
      }
    }

    if (socket && !support.connected) {
      socket.connect();
      getActiveSupportTickets();
    }
  }, [dispatch, support.connected, support.selectedChatRoom?.id, getActiveSupportTickets, socketReady]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (support.userId && support.token && support.applicationId) {
      setSocket(io(socketIoServer,
        {
          transports: ['websocket'],
          query: {
            token: support.token,
            applicationId: support.applicationId
          }
        }));
      setSocketReady(true);
    }
  }, [support.applicationId, support.token, support.userId]);
```

This is the server side code (NodeJS):

```
export const initSocketIO = (server: any) => {
  // const { Server } = require("socket.io");
  // const io = new Server(server);

  const io = require("socket.io")(server);

  io.on("connection", async (socket: Socket) => {
    logger.info(`user is connecting...`);

    let token = socket.handshake.query.token;
    let applicationId = socket.handshake.query.applicationId;

    .....
```

It does not even reach the `io.on("connection", ...`

The error:

> [Error] WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://support.xxxxxx.com/socket.io/?token=xxxxx&applicationId=xxxxxx&EIO=4&transport=websocket'
> failed: There was a bad response from the server.

This is so weird because it works on Android without any problem. I have checked the client code, it calls `socket.connect()` and it does not even continue to `socket.on('connect')`.

So from `socket.connect()` it just ends.

If I click the error message on the debug console, it shows this:

[image]

I am using `socket.io 4.5.1` and `socket.io-client 4.5.1`

---

### ON ERROR MESSAGE

This is the error message I got from the `socket.on("connect_error")`

> websocket error

Which does not tell me anything

---

DEBUGGING FROM THE SERVER

This is what I got from server log:

> 2022-06-19T04:10:44.809Z engine handshaking client
> "KddXP_t6guQ2dxHwAABK" 2022-06-19T04:10:44.809Z socket.io:server
> incoming connection with id KddXP_t6guQ2dxHwAABK              Node.js
>
> 2022-06-19T04:10:46.125Z socket.io:client no namespace joined yet,
> close the client 2022-06-19T04:10:46.125Z socket.io:client forcing
> transport close 2022-06-19T04:10:46.125Z socket.io:client client close
> with reason forced close 2022-06-19T04:10:46.125Z socket.io:client
> client close with reason forced server close              Node.js
>
> 2022-06-19T04:10:50.706Z engine handshaking client
> "Y_yOM8oTDtT8sgntAABL" 2022-06-19T04:10:50.706Z socket.io:server
> incoming connection with id Y_yOM8oTDtT8sgntAABL              Node.js
>
> 2022-06-19T04:10:52.615Z socket.io:client no namespace joined yet,
> close the client 2022-06-19T04:10:52.615Z socket.io:client forcing
> transport close 2022-06-19T04:10:52.615Z socket.io:client client close
> with reason forced close 2022-06-19T04:10:52.615Z socket.io:client
> client close with reason forced server close

These continue as the client keeps trying to reconnect.